# Refresh Div elements withoud reload Page using Ajax and DJango

Tags: python, ajax, django

I read many posts in site about refresh elements without reload page, but i can't fix my problem. I have a view called 'operation' and i need refresh these page each 5 seconds. Then, i created a other view called 'refresh' to update my data.

But it returns error 404 when i open the page. How can i fix the problem?
'POST /operation/refresh HTTP/1.1 404 2317'

views.py

```
def main(request):
    dp_col = DataDisplay.objects.all()
    #print(dp_col[0].name)
    reg = Registers.objects.latest('pk')
    context = {
        'dp_col': dp_col,
        'reg':reg
    }
    return render(request,'operation.html',context)

def refresh(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        reg = Registers.objects.latest('pk')
        print(reg)
        #return render(request,'operation.html',{'reg':reg})
        return HttpResponse({'reg':reg})
```

operation.js

```
function refresh_function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'refresh',
        success: function(data){
            //atualizar os dados da página
            alert(data);
        }
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sp_pumpspeed').slider({
        formatter: function(value){
            return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }}),

    setInterval(refresh_function,1000); 

});
```

Comment: You need to at least show us your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more I'm guessing that you're receiving a 404 since you have hard-coded the URL as "refresh" in the $.ajax() call which is obviously not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I forget the add a line in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^refresh/',views.refresh,name='refresh')
```

This resolve my problem.
Thanks!